# select all table with join by where

Tags: mysql

Two tables:

```
table1  
id | name
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc

table2
id | param
1  | x
1  | z
2  | x

table1.id = table2.id
```

I need to select everything from table1, with field `param` (1 if have, 0 if no, or null) by given `param`.

For example, by `param` "x":

```
result:
id | name | param
1  | aaa  | 1
2  | bbb  | 1
3  | ccc  | 0
```

All I can do is just:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.param
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.param = 'x'
```

But it doesn't select all `table1`.
What is the right query for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the filter AFTER the join.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.param
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id and table2.param='x'
```

Comment: And `CASE WHEN table2.param IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS param `